# Make unittest.mock.Mock() return list of dicts

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock a call of method `extra_get()` which usually returns a list of dicts. As far as I understand from the Mock [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock), if I want to return iterable, I should set side_effect param.

```
client.extra_get = mock.Mock(
            **{'side_effect': [{'foo': 'bar'}]})
```

But then the following code calls that mocked method:

```
extra = client.extra_get(request, type_id)
result = {x.key: x.value for x in extra}
return result
```

And the dict comprehention fails because `extra` there is not a list, but dict `{'foo': 'bar'}`.
What I'm doing wrong? How can I make Mock method return a list of dicts?

Comment: [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) takes a list, so you can return a different thing each time (*"If side_effect is an iterable then each call to the mock will return the next value from the iterable"*). Either use [`return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value), which takes a single thing to return every time, or provide a list of lists of dictionaries.

Comment: @jonrsharpe tried it initially. But if I use `client.extra_get.return_value = mock.Mock(**{'return_value': [{'foo': 'bar'}]})` I'm getting `TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable` error.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] demonstrating that issue, then.

Answer (score 3):

```
with mock.patch.object(client, 'extra_get', return_value=[{...}, {...}]) as mock_get:
  # fill in the rest
```